# Menu is not highlighted when viewing its corresponding page

Tags: 7, routes

I'm using D7. In it, one of the menu in left sidebar is not highlighted when viewing its corresponding page.

Case 1 : If I gave the path to the menu link as `node/15`, it is highlighted but the anonymous user can't see the menu at all.

Case 2: If the path will be www.sitename.com/blah/blahbla means its not highlighted and the anonymous user can see this menu.

Since that page is not to be accessible by anonymous user, hence this problem?
Can any one help me to get rid of this?

Comment: in *case 2*, is the anonymous user able to access the menu? or is s/he getting an *Access denied* message?

Comment: The anonymous can see the menu but not having access the see the page which is corresponding to the menu.I wanna all the users must see the menu but only the allowed users can view the page, and while viewing the page the menu must be highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

I put a condition for that node and added the style for the menu in the page.tpl.I don't know is this is the right solution.But it worked for me.